# Wifi not working on compaq 6715b running ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, drivers, laptop

I'm trying to get WIFI running on an old compaq 6715b laptop. It does not show up in iwconfig, so I assume that I need to install drivers. I've tried using ndiswrapper, and tried "sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms" and similar, but nothing works. It still does not show up, and google is running out of novel suggestions.

I don't know which outputs from console are necessary to provide any feedback, so tell me if you need anything!

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I had to solve the problem myself for a friend's machine this week, so here it goes... Just giving the laptop model does not help, because often the same model is delivered with different components in different countries or different product variants or depending on the build week.

```
sudo lspci -v
```

... shows what model of network adapter you have and whether a kernel driver has been loaded for it.

In my case it was a BCM43xx and it had loaded the b43 kernel driver.

```
dmesg | grep b43
```

... revealed the problem: The driver complained about missing firmware.

Googling a bit brought up the Debian/Ubuntu package `firmware-b43-installer`. I installed it into another machine running Ubuntu and copied the 2 firmware files that the driver had complained about using a USB stick. (Because the target had no network.) Of course if your distro is compatible, you can transfer the `deb` file and install it on the target.

Next problem was the kill switch. Probably a previous Windows had left a soft kill value of "blocked" in the NVRAM. I don't know how to change that (short of booting to Windows temporarily and change it), so you have to unblock the switch every time after booting the machine (that could be scripted). The hard kill switch (well, touch area on the LED panel...) worked perfectly out of the box. For these exercises the `rfkill` command line program is your friend. It's straight forward to use, just read the help.

(On OpenSUSE the firmware installer package is called `pullin-bcm43xx-firmware`.)